# Can any one help me what went wrong in the below query. While running the query I got this error :Query 1: Unknown column 'START' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT
  d.`hostname`,
  d.`ip`,
  d.`sysdesc`,
  d.`status`,
  d.`snmpable`,
  d.`uptime`,
  d.`lastknowngood`,
  d.`lastchange`,
  d.`lastpoll`,
  d.`modules`,
  d.`serial`,
  d.`mem_free`,
  d.`dns_ip`
FROM
  `devices` as d
  LEFT JOIN `pwan` as p ON p.`hostname` = d.`hostname`
WHERE
  (
    d.`hostname` LIKE '%.router.enta.net'
    OR p.`hostname` IS NOT NULL
    OR d.`hostname` LIKE '%.viper.enta.net'
    AND d.`os` = 'FreeBSD'
  )
  AND d.`status` = '0'
  and START BETWEEN (
    DATE_FORMAT (d.`lastchange`, '%Y-%m-%d:%h:%m') >= '2022-08-12:16:00'
  )
  AND (
    DATE_FORMAT(d.`lastchange`, '%Y-%m-%d:%h:%m') <= '2022-08-15:12:00'
  )
  and End BETWEEN (
    DATE_FORMAT (d.`lastchange`, '%Y-%m-%d:%h:%m') >= '2022-08-12:16:00'
  )
  AND (
    DATE_FORMAT(d.`lastchange`, '%Y-%m-%d:%h:%m') <= '2022-08-15:12:00'
  )
ORDER BY
  d.`lastchange` DESC
```

Comment: Can you format your SQL properly?

Comment: In the `WHERE` clause you reference a column called `START`.  The query engine can't find that column in the data.  Do you have any information which suggests otherwise?

Comment: I need to get data between 2 dates.

Comment: @jarlh I have edited the query can you check now?

Comment: Isn't *start* reserved? (as in start transaction). In this case use \`start\`

Comment: @Déjàvu, `start` is a keyword, but not a _reserved_ keyword, therefore it does not require delimiters. See explanation of the difference here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

Comment: you need to edit the question and show the COMPLETE DDL (table definition) for all the tables in the query.

Comment: Also, your use of OR and AND is troublesome when using one one set of parenthesis. Maybe your closed paren is in the wrong place.

Comment: Which table do the columns START and END belong to? It's good programming practice to _qualify_ all columns (at least when several tables are involved.)

Comment: Why are you using `>=` and `<=` in your `BETWEEN` arguments? This will turn into something like `START BETWEEN TRUE AND FALSE`

Answer (score 2):

There are no `START` and `End` columns in your tables.

I think what you want is:

```
AND d.lastchange BETWEEN '2022-08-12 16:00:00' and '2022-08-15 12:00:59'
```

There's no need to use `DATE_FORMAT()`. You can compare a `DATETIME` to a string, and it will parse the string for the comparison.

Comment: @Barman Nice catch!